# how to run different versions of rails like 3.0 and 2.3.5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

how to run different versions of rails like 3.0 and 2.3.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the best solution is to use something like rvm http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/

build to different gemsets, one for each version of rails, and

`rvm use 1.8.7@rails2.3.5` ... to create an app in that branch of rails, etc

you can also scope gemsets to projects and add aliases, to make it easier.

Finally, Bundler can be used, at the project level, but rails less than 3.0.0 do not require using Bundler so you need to change the setup of your app to do it. Instrutions are available on bundler's site: http://gembundler.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try to use rvm 
you can install multiple rubies and with the help of the gemsets you can have multiple rails versions too for each ruby. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) and gemsets, or bundler.